# Most significant content keywords in Google Webmaster Tools are not on my website

Tags: google-search-console

There are multiple content keywords in the *content keyword* list of the Google Webmaster Tools that are not on my website.

For example, according to that list, the word *one* appears 6 times on my site (number 1 on the list) but in reality it appears not even once. Other words that are in the list, but not on my website are *webbhotell*, *billiga*, *domän*, *cloud*, *daglig*, etc.

My website is hosted on `one.com` so I guess it has something to do with that. Anyone having the same problems with `one.com` and Google Webmaster Tools?

Comment: Jens, you may want to use a backlinks checker like https://ahrefs.com/ to make sure that it's not due to someone else building bogus links to your site. A well designed web host shouldn't pass their keywords onto their customers, but it may be worth reporting it to them as a bug, it's possible something is wrong with their settings. Finally, I'd check your meta descriptions etc. to see if they appear in the code somewhere.

Comment: When you say "hosted on one.com" do you mean as a subdomain, or do you have your own domain name?

Comment: @DrewCopenhaver According to ahrefs.com their are no backlinks. I checked the meta descriptions, there's nothing wrong with it. Thanks anyway!

Comment: @StephenOstermiller I have my own domain: [link](http://www.bucoplan.be)

Comment: @JensCocquyt That's actually good because it gives you more information when troubleshooting. These are the kinds of things you need to check before you call your hosting provider and complain that they've misconfigured a setting or something. Stephen makes a good point. If it's a subdomain, there's not much you can do about passing keywords, but if one.com is just hosting your own, separate site, this kind of thing shouldn't happen and you need to contact their technical support.

Comment: The problem has solved itself by waiting a couple of weeks. Thank anyway!

Answer (score 2):

Google Webmaster Tools content keyword list is for the entire website and the report is the aggregation of all keywords on all pages that Google has crawled.

I assume 3 reasons:

1. You have those keywords on pages that you've not visited yourself yet! For example you have them on your 404 page, but you've not visited the page so far.
2. Google considers all keywords on the site, including the ones that are hidden to users via browser like meta keywords. Search the keywords on your pages HTML source and you will probably find them.
3. If you've changed your site recently, you may see old keywords there, so you have to wait until Google updates it.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I know that the keyword list is a result of the crawling of all the pages but words like _one_ and _webbhotell_ are none of the pages. Reason 1: I know all te pages and a have a custom 404 page [link](http://www.bucoplan.be). Reason 2: I've written the meta tags myself and i checked them again, the words are not in there. Reason 3: Maybe it has something to do with that, i'll ask the one.com helpdesk if they had similar problems.

Comment: According to the One.com helpdesk this problem could occur because Google hasn't indexed my website yet. This is strange because the Google Webmasters Tool says it has already indexed all my pages. Anyhow, I submitted them again for indexing and I'll wait a couple more days. I'll let it know if something changes.

Comment: The problem has solved itself by waiting a couple of weeks!